# Do neutrinos in long baseline accelerators flight in matter and short baseline ones flight in vacuum, or are there exceptions?

Tags: neutrinos, particle-accelerators

Do neutrinos in long baseline experiments with accelerators flight in matter (Earth) and short baseline ones flight in vacuum, or are there exceptions ?

Why don't long baseline neutrino experiments with accelerators use a vacuum inside earth, in the spirit of LHC has created : it would be much "more easy" as compared to LHC, since there is no need of bending nor accelerating structure in the long flight region (since neutrino have been already created and go in a straigth path). Is it just a problem of cost of excavation ?

Comment: Keep in mind that with short-baseline accelerator (as opposed to reactor) experiments while the decay-in-flight beam line is in vacuum it is followed by a massive beam-stop, and any tunnel that exists there after is not in vacuum but is air filled.

Comment: @dmckee : thank you : what you say is very important.

Comment: @dmckee : but did they put air instead of vacuum : for a short baseline, it should be manageable in terms of money ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're asking about experiments where an accelerator. produces a beam of neutrinos which is observed in a detector hundreds of miles away. For example, there is a neutrino detector in South Dakota which is the target of a neutrino beam created near Chicago, and there is a detector in Italy which is the target of a beam produced in Switzerland.

Over those distances the curvature of the Earth is significant. If you know trigonometry you can figure out how deep an evacuated tunnel would have to be to be to make a straight- line connection.  (For two cities 200km apart on the surface, the tunnel is nearly 1km below the surface at the midpoint between them.)  Building a vacuum tunnel hundreds of miles long and miles deep is not technology that we have developed.

Comment: All right thank you. So at the opposite, do short baseline experiment never cross the Earth ?

Comment: Strangely, the use of both km and miles doesn't perturb me as much as I think it should.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian Some short-baseline experiments may have the neutrino source and/or detector underground, but the matter effect requires a nontrivial flight distance to become important.

Comment: @KyleKanos I'm wasn't where I could look up Earth's radius in miles, but I'm American enough that "hundreds of kilometers" sounds forced to my ear. I almost wrote "hundreds of kilometers (sixties of miles)" but decided that would cause more confusion than it removed.

Comment: @rob : thank you. Everything is clear.